# Zend Framework code documentation style

Tags: php, zend-framework, documentation, phpdoc

I was wondering why there's two blocks of comments with repeated information. Does someone knows the answer?

```
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@zend.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Controller
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 * @version    $Id: Action.php 23775 2011-03-01 17:25:24Z ralph $
 */

/**
 * @see Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker
 */
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/HelperBroker.php';

/**
 * @see Zend_Controller_Action_Interface
 */
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action/Interface.php';

/**
 * @see Zend_Controller_Front
 */
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Front.php';

/**
 * @category   Zend
 * @package    Zend_Controller
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license    http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd     New BSD License
 */
abstract class Zend_Controller_Action implements Zend_Controller_Action_Interface
{
```

For example: @category, @package, @copyright, @license. Those repeat twice on the first  and second comment block.

I was looking for the commenting best practices and while analyzing their code, I've came up with this question.

Please, do not blame me if it's too much simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zend Framework use **phpDocumentator** to render their Technical Documentation.

The behavior you noticed is how phpDocumentator reads a file and parse it, there are two ways a @package tag can be parsed:

- page-level package (defines, functions, includes)
- class-level package (class, variables, methods)

A @license and @copyright page can be associated to any element (include, page, define, method, variable, etc)

A good resource in order to realize a great documentation is [the phpDoc official manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/).

Comment: Thank you Liyali. My knowledge about the phpdoc tool it self is poor. So far I have just commented my code through the IDE, but not from its tool. I will take a look at and figure it out.

Comment: More to the origination of this practice of the two docblocks -- phpDocumentor _requires_ a file-level docblock AND a class-level docblock.  It won't crash if it doesn't find them, but it will list this missing item as an "error" in the errors.html file that it creates when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this for a fact, but would assume it's because they have a separate, pre-defined template for what goes at the top of a PHP file and for the documentation block above a class. In files that also contain a class, you'll find this duplication.

Comment: It seems pretty reasonable. But I'm wondering why is that, because generally the second comment block does not contain anything else than that duplicated vars (I haven't seen any classes yet that has something else).

Comment: This is incorrect, @liyali has the right answer.